# How to share header files among multiple projects?

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio

I have to share header files to define structs among multiple projects. For example, There are A and B project in the Solution. I want to share x.h, y.h and z.h among them. I won't create any .cpp for shared files. so there will be no .lib and .dll for shared ones.

I try creating new project for shared files in that solution and using it as git submodule or subtree. Is there much better idea to do this on Visual Studio ?

Comment: There's something called *header only libraries*. These are basically projects that contain nothing more than header files. Why not simply make such a project, add an `include` directory, and put the common header files there? Then make the other projects depend on the header only project, and add the header only project `include` directory to the other projects search paths for header files. Should work fine as long as all the projects are in the same VS workspace.

Comment: Thank you. I hear the concept of header only libraries for the first time.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Hi, consider converting comment to answer. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

There is C++ shared item project in Visual Studio.
You could refer to [Share source code across multiple C++ projects](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cross-platform-code-sharing-with-visual-c/)

> These “shared items” projects don’t participate in build but they can
> contain any number of C++ headers and sources.